# Should we have a different action type for every time we update a react context state?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-context

Say we have built everything in a large Context and we are using this context for state management (maybe better suited with redux... but regardless...)

Do we want to have a new action type for every time we want to update one property of the state? Or should we have a generic action like `UPDATE_STATE` in the reducer that handles the times we have a simple change that doesn't really have any reduction logic.

For example:

```
switch(action.type) {
  case "SET_MODAL":
    return {
      ...state,
      isModalOpen: action.isModalOpen
    }
  case "SET_ERROR_MSG":
    return {
      ...state,
      errMsg: action.errMsg
    }
  case "SET_HAS_CLICKED_THING":
    return {
      ...state,
      clickedThing: action.clickedThing
    }
   // ***ALOT MORE OF THESE^^^***
   // ***ALOT MORE OF THESE^^^***
  case "GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS":
    const { items } = action
    const newItems = items.map(*some reduction change logic that is not standard*)
    return {
      ...state,
      items: newItems
    }
}
```

vs

```
switch(action.type) {
  case "UPDATE_STATE":
    return {
      ...state,
      ...action.state
    }
  case "GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS":
    const { items } = action
    const newItems = items.map(*some reduction change logic that is not standard*)
    return {
      ...state,
      items: newItems
    }
}
```

It seems like we will have a large list of actions that Im not sure is adding value. Really we just want to store a value in the state. Do we really need an action for every time we just want to update the state?

Comment: Action type should ideally reflect the *intention* of your business logic. And it should not be interfered by shape of your data structure.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. So we should have many action types even if it is simply updating the state

Comment: Well…yes and no. I don’t think you ask the right question. I’m saying multiple action types or not, it should not be determined by your state shape. The real concern should be, how would the API end up be like? Is it clear enough in terms of code readability? I don’t mind to have a single action type handling multiple prop change, as long as this approach doesn’t mess up my code readability.

Comment: Say you go with single action type `UPDATE_STATE`, but everywhere you dispatch you always use some action creator, like `dispatch(openModal())` then the intention is clearly expressed. The fact that you use a single action type is hidden by action creator, and it becomes an implementation detail that doesn’t hurt. Don’t ask for over simplified rules to follow, think about the implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you. But I would choose the first way. It seems more readable and much better to see data flow. Defining actions helps you to debug easily and find out what happens in the app.